# Swift 3 Need Help On Realm Query

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I have two model class

```
class EntryModel: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var type: String = ""
    dynamic var tap: Int = 0
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var notes: String = ""
    dynamic var startTime: Date? = nil
    dynamic var endTime: Date? = nil
    dynamic var amount1: Int = 0
    dynamic var amount2: Int = 0
    dynamic var meal: String = ""
    dynamic var foodDetails: String = ""
    dynamic var isAlarm: Bool = false
    dynamic var timeOfAlarm: Date? = nil
    //dynamic var lastFeedTime: Date? = nil // optionals supported

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

and

```
class EntryModelList: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var babyId: Int = 0
    dynamic var date: Date? = nil
    var entryModel = List<EntryModel>()
    //dynamic var lastFeedTime: Date? = nil // optionals supported

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I am new in realm so I don't know much about it. I want a query which will return me by filtering with babyId of EntryModelList and type of EntryModel. The which will match only this list I want.

I have tried with

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "babyId == \(babyId) AND ANY entryModel.type IN %@", filterArray)
 let entryModelList = try! Realm().objects(EntryModelList.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)
```

Predicate output :

```
babyId == 1 AND ANY entryModelList.type IN {"breast", "bottle"}
```

Output:

```
Results<EntryModelList> (
    [0] EntryModelList {
        id = 2;
        babyId = 1;
        date = 2017-02-16 18:00:00 +0000;
        entryModelList = RLMArray <0x6100000ff480> (
            [0] EntryModel {
                id = 8;
                type = diaper;
                tap = 1;
                title = ;
                notes = ;
                startTime = 2017-02-17 11:26:36 +0000;
                endTime = (null);
                amount1 = 0;
                amount2 = 0;
                meal = ;
                foodDetails = ;
                isAlarm = 0;
                timeOfAlarm = (null);
            },
            [1] EntryModel {
                id = 10;
                type = bottle;
                tap = 1;
                title = ;
                notes = Fgdg;
                startTime = 2017-02-16 23:44:22 +0000;
                endTime = (null);
                amount1 = 15;
                amount2 = 0;
                meal = ;
                foodDetails = ;
                isAlarm = 0;
                timeOfAlarm = (null);
            }
        );
    },
    [1] EntryModelList {
        id = 1;
        babyId = 1;
        date = 2017-02-14 18:00:00 +0000;
        entryModelList = RLMArray <0x6100000fd680> (
            [0] EntryModel {
                id = 1;
                type = breast;
                tap = 0;
                title = ;
                notes = ;'l'k,;
                startTime = 2017-02-14 23:15:49 +0000;
                endTime = (null);
                amount1 = 100;
                amount2 = 0;
                meal = ;
                foodDetails = ;
                isAlarm = 0;
                timeOfAlarm = (null);
            },
            [1] EntryModel {
                id = 4;
                type = bottle;
                tap = 0;
                title = ;
                notes = Jhkhjkhjk;
                startTime = 2017-02-15 01:17:47 +0000;
                endTime = (null);
                amount1 = 100;
                amount2 = 0;
                meal = ;
                foodDetails = ;
                isAlarm = 0;
                timeOfAlarm = (null);
            },
            [2] EntryModel {
                id = 7;
                type = breast;
                tap = 0;
                title = ;
                notes = ;
                startTime = 2017-02-15 11:43:08 +0000;
                endTime = (null);
                amount1 = 100;
                amount2 = 0;
                meal = ;
                foodDetails = ;
                isAlarm = 0;
                timeOfAlarm = (null);
            }
        );
    }
)
```

but this is not what I want. I want to know how I will get only those data list where EntryModel.type is "breast" or "bottle" type.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some example data showing what you want your query to match vs what it actually matches? It's hard to understand from your description what it is you want the query to do differently.

Comment: @bdash I have updated my question and please let me know you can understand my question or not. My english is not so good. If you can give me a solution I will be humble to you. Thanks

Comment: Is your intent to end up with a `Results<EntryModelList>` where each contained `EntryModelList`'s `entryModelList` property is filtered so it only contains objects with the appropriate `type` property?

Comment: Yes.. This is what i want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Results.filter(_:)` only allows for filtering which objects of the given type are included in the result set. It does not support filtering which objects are included in values of properties on those objects.

To do what you're after you'd need to use `filter(_:)` on each of the `entryModelList` properties of the objects you're working with to include only those you're interested in.